# сокеты и https

Tags: сокеты, php, https

Здравствуйте Жители ХешКода, мой вопрос стоит по поводу сокетов в php и https.
Вот код каторый стучится к серверу http

```
...
fwrite($socket, "POST /post/test.php HTTP/1.1\r\n");
fwrite($socket, "Host: www.example.loc\r\n");
...
```

А вот как выполнить такой же запрос по протоколу https (мне нужно узнать что нужно написать за место HTTP/1.1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам не вместо `HTTP/1.1` писать надо (не додумывайте ответы).

В PHP сокеты нормально ездят по защищенному транспорту. Пишете просто:

```
$socket = fsockopen("ssl://www.example.org", 443, $errno, $errstr, 60);
```

то есть, во-первых, не забудьте правильный порт, во-вторых, используйте схему `ssl://`